# Pandas access first column with duplicate column names

Tags: pandas, duplicates, slice

Looking for some help accessing the first empty df column that is also a duplicate name, by name.

Consider this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'], index=[0,1,2,3])
     A    B    C    C    C    C    D    E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

then access a slice by indexer and column name

```
indexer = [1,3]
df.loc[indexer, 'C']

     C    C    C    C
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I want to edit only the first instance of column C so that I get

```
     A    B    C    C    C    C    D    E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN   99  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN   99  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I tried df.loc[indexer, 'C'].iloc[:,0] = 99

But it did not set the values.

Thanks in advance for your replies and ideas.

Comment: I would seriously consider de-duplicating your column index (or at least adding a second level). You're likely going to run into issues with several rather standard calculations. For instance `df.groupby(df.index//2).C.size()` is an odd output and `df.groupby(df.index//2).C.count()` just fails.

Comment: Thanks, as I go along the columns do get renamed.  C stays named C, then on a loop I decide first C is notnull and the next C is renamed and populated.  I use up and rename all 4 Cs in this way.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
indexer = [1, 3]
col = (df.columns == 'C').argmax()
df.iloc[indexer, col] = 99
df

     A    B    C    C    C    C    D    E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN   99  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN   99  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use  [`index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to get the slice of integer location of columns `C` and passing its `start` to `.iloc` as follows:

```
indexer = [1, 3]
df.iloc[indexer, df.columns.get_loc('C').start] = 99
```

---

Or using `np.nonzero`

```
c_loc = np.nonzero(df.columns == 'C')[0]    
df.iloc[indexer, c_loc[0]] = 99


Out[87]:
     A    B    C    C    C    C    D    E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN   99  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN   99  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```